# SELF Referential SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my MS SQL Database called PolicyTransactions. This table has two important columns:

```
trans_id  INT IDENTITY(1,1),
policy_id INT NOT NULL,
```

I need help writing a query that will, for each trans_id/policy_id in the table, join it to the last previous trans_id for that policy_id. This seems like a simple enough query, but for some reason I can't get it the gel in my brain right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cooked this up for you.... Hopefully its what you're looking for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7dc39/8

Basically, a `cross apply` is different from a `subquery` or regular `join`. It is a query that gets executed per each row that the outer portion of the query returns. This is why it has visibility into the outer tables (a subquery would not have this ability) and this is why its using the old school join syntax (old school meaning the `join` condition on **_ = _** is in the `where` clause).

Just be really careful with this solution as cross apply isn't necessarily the fastest thing on earth. However, if the indexing on the tables is decent, that tiny query should run pretty quickly.

Its the only way I could think of to solve it, but it doesn't mean its the only way!

just a super quick edit: If you notice, some rows are not returned because they are the FIRST policy and therefore don't have a tran_id less than them with the same policy number. If you want to simulate an `outer join` with an apply, use `outer apply` :)

Comment: 1) Thank you for the answer, you are awesome. and 2) Oh my, I never knew about SQLfiddle. That is so awesome too!

Comment: no problem! sqlfiddle is outstanding! a bit sluggish at times, but with what its capable of.... I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later you should use the [LAG()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function.  See snippet below, I feel that its much cleaner than the other answer given here.

```
SELECT trans_id, policy_id, LAG(trans_id) OVER (PARTITION BY policy_id ORDER BY trans_id)
FROM PolicyTransaction
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, I am targeting 2008 still with this. But that is a very interesting method they added. I will have to play around with it on my local box. THanks!

Comment: it is cleaner, though it targets just one (or i suppose 2 now) versions of MSSQL and isn't a very well known function. Windowed functions won't typically perform much better than cross apply/outer apply.... but that is a super cool function nonetheless